# Add socket.io on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm testing socket.io with nodejs.

This is what I have on my server side :

```
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization");
    next();
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

And this is what I have on my client side :

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
```

And I get a 404 :

```
socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LTYKOs3
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LTYKOs3. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I've been looking on forums to get answers about origins and adding information to header, but nothing seems to work.

Any help plz ? 
Thanks

Comment: Replace `var io =  ...` with : `var io = require('socket.io')(); io.listen(http);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines of code:

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

to this:

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Your code was creating a second server that was not on port 3000 and binding socket.io to that other server so when you tried to use socket.io on port 3000, it wasn't connecting to the a server that had socket.io on it.  My code suggestion binds socket.io to the  one express server on port 3000 and does not create a second server.